# Long-running transaction?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, web-applications

After user registred, he usualy try log in, but he usually can't do that with fist attempt, sometimes it needs some time to succesfully log in. So, what is behinde the scene:

```
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session hSession = factory.openSession();

    Transaction tx = null;
    List<UserTable> list1 = null;

    try {
        tx = hSession.beginTransaction();
        Criteria crit = hSession.createCriteria(UserTable.class).add(
                Restrictions.like("email", email));
        list1 = crit.list();
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        hSession.close();
    }

    // the 'if' is usualy 'true' after some time...
    if(list1.size() > 0) {
        String hash = null;
        try {
            hash = EncryptPassword.encryptPassword(password);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        if (list1.get(0).getPassword().equals(hash)) {
            session.put("email", email);
            log.info("login successful: " + email);
            return SUCCESS;
        } else {
            log.info(email + " - the deer does't remember password");
        }
    }

    addActionError(getText("error.login"));
    // the next warning usually happens twice or more
    log.warn("login error: " + email);
    return ERROR;
```

What is this? A long-running transaction or something other?

Comment: Do you have some broken level 2 caching turned on?

Comment: @BoristheSpider No, hibernate config does not using any special cashing setttings. Does it need it?

Comment: Okay. Have you verified that the data is committed to the database by the registration process?

Comment: Right after register I check the database -  user is there. 
And after that I try to log in but situation as I describes earlier.
Also,  hibernate uses Vibur DBCP pooling - maybe something with it?